# Wrong redirect_uri in Facebook login api

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-login, osqa

I am configuring the log in with Facebook in my website. When users are asked to introduce their email and password, Facebook will redirect to my website but the address is wrong:

> mywebsite.com/osqa/osqa/account/facebook/done...

As you can see "osqa" appears twice when it should be there only once.

The urls.py file contains the following script:

```
url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('account/'), _('signin/')), app.auth.signin_page, name='auth_signin'),
url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('account/'), _('signout/')), app.auth.signout, name='user_signout'),
url(r'^%s(?P<provider>\w+)/%s$' % (_('account/'), _('signin/')), app.auth.prepare_provider_signin, name='auth_provider_signin'),
url(r'^%s(?P<provider>\w+)/%s$' % (_('account/'), _('done/')), app.auth.process_provider_signin, name='auth_provider_done'),
url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('account/'), _('register/')), app.auth.external_register, name='auth_external_register'),
url(r'^%s%s(?P<user>\d+)/(?P<code>.+)/$' % (_('account/'), _('validate/')), app.auth.validate_email, name='auth_validate_email'),
url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('account/'), _('tempsignin/')), app.auth.request_temp_login, name='auth_request_tempsignin'),
url(r'^%s%s(?P<user>\d+)/(?P<code>.+)/$' % (_('account/'), _('tempsignin/')), app.auth.temp_signin, name='auth_tempsignin'),
url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/%s$' % (_('account/'), _('authsettings/')), app.auth.auth_settings, name='user_authsettings'),
url(r'^%s%s(?P<id>\d+)/%s$' % (_('account/'), _('providers/'), _('remove/')), app.auth.remove_external_provider, name='user_remove_external_provider'),
url(r'^%s%s%s$' % (_('account/'), _('providers/'), _('add/')), app.auth.signin_page, name='user_add_external_provider'),
url(r'^%s%s$' %(_('account/'), _('send-validation/')), app.auth.send_validation_email, name='send_validation_email'),
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Request https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=MY_API_KEY& redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html& scope=publish_stream,create_event
2. Facebook will redirect you to http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html? code=MY_VERIFICATION_CODE
3. Request https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_API_KEY& redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html& client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET&code=MY_VERIFICATION_CODE
4. Facebook will respond with access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN